# zsh selects a pasted text

Tags: x11, zsh, clipboard

Since some update of the zsh a new behaviour of the shell was appeared. I.e. now when I paste a text from the buffer (via the paste command or via the 3rd mouse button -- no matter) it "selected" -- the background of the inserted text is highlighted as if I had selected it. The selection is disappeared if I press a cursor movement keys, for example.

I use the zsh in the konsole terminal (KDE 5). Now versions of the programs are:

- konsole - 16.12
- zsh - 5.3
- grml-zsh-config - 0.12.6

My distro is the Arch.

Is there any chance to return an old behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you'd like to keep bracketed paste - the feature that causes this - enabled ([it improves safety](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/c160o2/command_line_pasted_text/erbdiqj/)), it's possible to simply disable the highlighting of pasted text by adding this to `~/.zshrc`:

```
zle_highlight=('paste:none')
```

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/c160o2/command_line_pasted_text/erbg6hy/)

Answer (score 5):

This feature was introduced with version 5.1 of *zsh*. You can disable it by [unsetting the variable `zle_bracketed_paste`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-bracketed-paste):

```
unset zle_bracketed_paste
```

**Note:** Aside from highlighting pasted text (which is, as far as I understand, actually done by the terminal) it also prevents *ZLE* from parsing special characters like tabs and newlines. This means for example that if you paste multiline text, *zsh* will not automatically (try to) run each line as if it were a command, instead the whole text will be pasted as a whole with literal tabs and newlines.